# Chrome extension to git commit

Tags: git, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension for chrome to run `git commit` each time I reload a page, but I can't find a way to execute a command from the chrome API. I came around doing it running a local http server and sending requests from the extension but this solution has too many dependencies and too much work for practically nothing and I feel like I am missing something. Especially while in firefox the same task was quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is, of course, to have a server/daemon you can connect to via HTTP/WebSockets - this is what you've done.

Another option is [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). You can make a simple script that Chrome will be able to invoke.

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense. As a tangent to my question, is it possible to package the host binary with a chrome extension or app and have a user install the whole thing like they would an NPAPI plugin?

Comment: No. That's the major downside of Native Messaging, you can't bundle the host component in the Chrome Web Store. You need a separate installer.